# Visual Studio Extensibility: ProvideAutoLoad for Package.cs for every UI Context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

My goal is to create a "Visual Studio Extensibility" which adds a "Npm install" Context Menu Item to a package.json file.

So far, this works great if I open a solution, because I've added the `[ProvideAutoLoad(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.UIContextGuids.SolutionExists)]` attribute to the Package class.

But it's not working if I open a Web Site (File->Open->Web Site...). Do you have any idea, how I can AutoLoad the Package.cs for every UI Context?

Edit: More information after further investigation: If I save the Web Site as a Solution, the "Initialize"-Method is called. But the BeforeQueryStatus of the MenuItem of package.json is not called. The solution structure looks like this:

```
-Solution
 -project
  -package.json
```

If I add the package.json directly into the solution, the Context Menu Item appears. Structure:

```
-Solution
 -Solution Items
  -package.json
 -project
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Add the below code to your package definition:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionHasMultipleProjects_string)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionHasSingleProject_string)]
```

Your package should load in all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the second ProvideAutoLoad attribute with the **NoSolution** value to load your package in all contexts.

Comment: It's still not working. I think it's somehow, because the "project" is not a real project, but a web site. Somehow, the parent seems to be another. So far, I add following parent to the button: `<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>`